# Objective C: retain vs alloc

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a singleton class with this code:

manager.h

```
@interface Manager : NSObject {
  NSString *jobsLimit;
  NSMutableDictionary *jobTitles;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *jobsLimit;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableDictionary *jobTitles;


@implementation Manager

@synthesize jobsLimit;
@synthesize jobTitles;

+ (id)sharedManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(shared == nil)
            shared = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return shared;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {  
        jobsLimit = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"50"];
        jobTitles = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then in the code i'm assigning these variables like this:

```
 self.jobsLimit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", progressAsInt];
 [self.jobTitles addEntriesFromDictionary:anotherDictionary];


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [jobsLimit release];
    [jobTitles release];
}
```

- Now my question is this code correct? Is the assignment correct?
- I'm very confused with when to use alloc and/or retain. Do I need to use alloc if my property is already retained? and If I use alloc should my property be assign?
- What will be the reference count now for these variables and will they be dealloc'd/under-dealloc'd when the dealloc is called?
- Also for singleton classes do I need to initialize my ivars as in the init method above or I do not have to.

I'd appreciate if someone can help me clear this confusion out and thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually looks correct, but perhaps some explanation is in order, since it sounds like you're a little unsure.

When you assign to a property that has `retain` semantics using the "." syntax, the accessor method calls `retain`. The "." syntax is just shorthand for invoking the accessor method, so

```
self.jobsLimit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", progressAsInt];
```

is exactly the same as

```
[self setJobsLimit:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", progressAsInt]];
```

That works out to:

- create an (autoreleased) string with a numeric value
- `retain` the string (you now own it) and assign it to `jobsLimit`

If, on the other hand, you assign to the iVar directly (not using the "."-accessor), the setter method is not called. For example:

```
jobsLimit = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"50"];
```

That is:

- allocate a string (you own it), with value "50"
- assign it to jobsLimit

Either way, you now own the string referred to by `jobsLimit`, and are responsible for eventually releasing it (e.g., in your `dealloc` method).

Comment: Thanks a lot David, but now the alloc'd string in "[[NSString alloc] .." will it ever gets dealloc'd since now jobsLimit is pointing to another string "[NString stringWith ..."???

Comment: As long as you use the accessor method (self.jobsLimit = ...) to assign, you'll be ok: the accessor method calls `release` on the old value before assigning the new one.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need a lot of this : [IOS Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)

and a bit of : [What should my Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like)

good lectures !